# How can I operate with MultiIndexed columns in pandas in specific levels?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

In pandas with simple columns, you can operate with columns quite straightfowardly. For example, if you have a DataFrame *df* with numeric columns **A** and **B**, you can compute:

```
df['C']=df['A']+df['B']
```

Using MultiIndex columns, you can do the same, as long as you operate on all levels of the MultiIndex. For example, if the columns of your DataFrame are **(A,X)**, **(A,Y)**, **(B,X)**, **(B,Y)**, you can write

```
df[('C','X')]=df[('A','X')]+df[('B','X')]
```

and the resulting DataFrame will have an additional column, **(C,X)** which equals `df[A,X]+df[B,X]`.

Which is the most straightforward way to do this on specific levels? More specifically, I'm looking for something like

```
df['C']=df['B']+df['A']
```

, which creates two columns **(C,X)** and **(C,Y)** which are equal to `df[A,X]+df[B,X]` and `df[A,Y]+df[B,Y]`, but this is a ValueError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `reshape` the dataframe to simplify the operations:

```
df.stack().eval('C = A + B').unstack()
```

Alternatively, you can use `concat` to append the extra level `C`:

```
df.join(pd.concat({'C': df['A'] + df['B']}, axis=1))
```

---

```
   A     B      C    
   X  Y  X  Y   X   Y
0  9  4  8  2  17   6
1  3  7  0  8   3  15
2  2  7  0  7   2  14
3  3  8  4  8   7  16
4  8  2  3  6  11   8
```